# Expected number of rolls on two fair dice until sum is seven...?

Tags: probability-theory

They put me this question on a test:

Two fair dice are rolled until the sum equals seven, or the dice are rolled twice. Let $X$ be the number of rolls in this experiment.

a) Find the expectation of $X$

b) Find the expectation of $X^2$

c) Find the variance of $X$

I had no idea. Hope anyone can answer this...

To clarify: the question was exactly like I wrote it; I copied it on a piece of paper I took with me 'cause it wasn't clear for me what the "or the dice are rolled twice" part meant; but they did gave me answer choices: $\dfrac 7 2$, $\dfrac {11} 6$, and three more that I don't remember but where less than one (I guess $\dfrac 5 {12}$, $\dfrac 5 {36}$ and $\dfrac 5 6$). The answer choices were the same for a), b) and c).

I tried to solve it this way:

a) There are $36$ possible outcomes and $6$ of them sum up $7$, so the probability of getting $7$ on the first throw is $\dfrac 6 {36} = \dfrac 1 6$. The expected number of rolls to get seven is then $E(X) = \dfrac 1 {\frac 1 6} = 6$, but it was not on the answer choices. 
So I tried to think of it in this other way: If the dice can only be rolled twice (at most) then your expected number of rolls must be $2$ minus the probability of getting the sum in the first throw: $E(X) = 2 - \dfrac 1 6 = \dfrac {11} 6$, which happens to be one of the answer choices, but I don't know if it's right.

For b) and c) I had no idea, so I guessed the answer.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: "Or the dice are rolled twice"?? Do you mean roll *one* die twice and sum??

Comment: I guess it means you have only two attempts to get the sum; it wasn't clear for me too.

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of $X$ is $P(X=1)=\frac{1}{6}$ and $P(X=2)=\frac{5}{6}.$
Then 
\begin{align*}
E[X] = 1\cdot \frac{1}{6}+2\cdot\frac{5}{6} = \frac{11}{6}.
\end{align*}
Similarly $E[X^2] = \frac{21}{6}$ and $\text{Var}[X] = \frac{5}{36}$.